# Inheritance & Virtual Interface in systemverilog?

Tags: oop, verilog, system-verilog

Multiple inheritance is very general OOPS concept, then why it is not implemented in systemverilog and only single inheritance is allowed?

2nd why interfaces are not allowed inside class? Is it because of storage implementation like dynamic storage in class and static in modules, programs, interface?

Answer (score 4):

This really should be two separate posts for your two distinct questions. Unfortunately the keyword ***interface*** will be used to answer both of them with entirely separate meanings.

I wrote a [2010 DVCon paper](http://www.eda.org/svdb/file_download.php?file_id=4250&type=bug) describing some of the reasons that multiple inheritance was not in the original SystemVerilog LRM, and possible solutions. SystemVerilog 1800-2012 did add multiple interface class inheritance and here is [a link](http://blog.verificationgentleman.com/2014/08/systemverilog-2012-has-even-more-class.html) to a good description of that feature. This use of the keyword **interface** as a kind of class has nothing to do with the **interface** in your 2nd question.

You are mostly correct about why interface instances are not allowed in classes. An SV **interface** is very similar to the design elements **module** and **program** that are instances of hierarchical containers. During the process of elaboration, these containers get flattened out before simulation begins. Class instances are only constructed at run-time by executing procedural code.

The elaboration process is particular to hardware description languages and is part of the the code generation  and replication process. It is also what allows you to hierarchically reference signals throughout the design without the use of pointers. Class objects on the other hand, are only referenced through dynamically created handles.

Comment: In your paper you mentioned the problem of diamond shape , but still in C++ we resolve it by using virtual class concept, so only one copy will be instantiated. So is something like that not possible in systemverilog?? 

And for virtual interface answer, I am not able to get how run time behaviour of class is related to not allowing interface in class, because ultimately everything regarding memory will be allocated in runtime only?

Comment: Unfortunately classes being constructed at run-time means that parameterised functions are generally not supported by synthesis tools (with the exception of DC).  There's a very strong case for an elaboration-time parameterisable container like a package to be added to the language as it seems to be impossible to persuade synthesis vendors to support classes for this purpose.

Comment: With a language designed by committee, anything is possible, and some things are impossible. Regardless of what is added to the language, it takes time and money for vendors to adopt.
@maheshShah, I will add more info above